# Python 2.7 run combinations on if, elif, elif statements

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I am trying to create a code that shows the connectivity of carbon atoms (denoted as 3D coordinates)

My code inputs an excel file that is organized as:

`carbon     x_coord  y_coord    z_coord
1           1.08     0.49       0.523
2           0.18     1.3        0.5
3           0.83     0.72       0.44`

Using

```
subset = cmd[['carbon','x_coord', 'y_coord','z_coord']]
coordinate_values = [tuple(x) for x in subset.values]
atoms = coordinate_values
atomPairs = itertools.combinations(atoms, 2)
```

I calculated the distance between each combination pair and sorted as below:

```
if d >= 1.4 and d < 1.6:
   print("The bond is a single bond")
elif d >= 1.2 and d < 1.4:
   print("The bond is a double bond")
elif d >= 1 and d < 1.2:
   print("The bond is a triple bond")
else:
    print("No bond exists")
```

to get the output (for each pair, showing only one below)

```
Computing distance between carbon_1 and carbon_1
The bond is a single bond
```

I'd now like to take all of these distances but only allow each carbon_ to have max four bonds (four "single", or two "single" and one "double", or one "single" and one "triple"), but four bonds are not required.

While I have no idea how to go about this, I would like to get an output similar to this:

```
carbon_1 is bonded to
single bond to carbon_2
single bond to carbon_3
single bond to carbon_4
carbon_1 is bonded to
single bond to carbon_2
triple bond to carbon_5
carbon_2 is bonded to
single bond to carbon_1
triple bond to carbon_6
```

Because with the amount of distances I have, I expect there to be multiple combinations of bonds for each carbon_

My idea was to do another if/elif statement to achieve this output, but I am very unsure how to start my code for this project. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens if the bond is exactly 1.4 (yeah floating point usually is not that exact), but I'm wondering? Furthermore there is also a gap between `1.2` and `1.21`...

Comment: It would be unlikely with the points I am using, but you are right I will fix that

Comment: Hint: Instead of `d >= 1.4 and d < 1.6` you can write `1.4 <= d < 1.6`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Could you add some pseudocode or something to demonstrate?

Comment: can you show us some sample data, and your desire output for that data?

Comment: There is still not enough information for anyone to give you substantial help... look at [mcve] and give us input/output examples as well as a solid  description of the problem you are solving.

Comment: You might be able to make variables storing the number of bonds for each carbon, and use `if` statements to make sure they are not over four bonds. Maybe after adding the bonds to the total number of bonds you can have the program check if it is over four bonds, and if it is, undo what it just did. I think you mean that it adds the bonds between the carbons automatically?

Comment: @AlexIndeglia Should the output for your example set be `(1-2: double, 1-3: None, 2-3: None)`? Please provide input and expected output.

Comment: How do you want to treat aromatic bonds, e.g. in toluene C6H5-CH3 ? Even though distance is known to b 1.4 sharp, due to rounding errors you may end up with 1 + 2 + 2 = 5 bound carbon.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the issue can be in 1.4 margin.

Yes, in aromatic cycles distance is known to be 1.4 sharp. What if because of the rounding errors solely the distance is calculated as 1.399999999 ? You end up with 6-bound carbons, numbered 4a and 8a in the picture:

[image]